Keyboard and mouse input simulation/automation tools not working properly in Ubuntu
I'm facing an issue with obtaining accurate mouse positions using pynput, pyautogui, and xdotool. Here’s what I’ve tried:
Pynput
from pynput.mouse import Controller
mouse = Controller()
print('Mouse position:', mouse.position)

Pyautogui
import pyautogui
print('Mouse position:', pyautogui.position())

xdotool
xdotool getmouselocation

All of these are giving same output

x:1919 y:748

My screen resolution is 1920x1080
And the keypresses are not working either.
All methods are giving me coordinates near the edge of the screen, but my mouse is actually positioned in the middle. I’ve confirmed the following:

Screen resolution is set correctly.
Display scaling is at 100%.
No virtual desktops or multiple monitors are in use.

I’m running these commands in Ubuntu. Is there something I'm missing or a potential issue with my setup?

It sounds like your setup is correct, but your measurement of the middle of the screen (1919, 748) is what it would be near if the resolution was actually (3840, 2160).  Can you include the pyautogui.size() call as part of your question, does that output (1920, 1080)?
